# Specifying more than 3 instances of a foreign key within a specific column with a SQL query?

Tags: sql

I have this query I'm attempting to execute:

```
SELECT employees.ename
FROM employees
JOIN certified ON certified.eid = employees.eid
JOIN aircraft ON aircraft.aid = certified.aid
WHERE aircraft.aid = (certified.aid > 3)
GROUP BY employees.ename;
```

What I'm attempting to do is return all the certified pilots (employees.ename and the first join) who are certified on **more than three** aircraft (second join & WHERE statement). But the above returns nothing. Sorry if there is an obvious answer, I'm very new to SQL and am self-teaching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query indeed appears likely to return no results, as the filter predicate (`aircraft.aid = (certified.aid > 3)`) is likely to be inconsistent with one of your join criteria (`aircraft.aid = certified.aid`) for most rows, if not all of them.  Indeed, the filter predicate, although it may be technically valid, doesn't make much sense.

I infer that you have a separate row in table `certified` describing each employee's certification for each aircraft, and what you're after is to identify those employees who have at least three such records.  Since each row of the join will associate a specific employee with a specific aircraft, you need to aggregate those rows to gain information from groups of them.  SQL has aggregate functions for this purpose.

However, an aggregate query can select only the columns on which the groups are based and aggregate functions of the groups, and although you can group by `employees.ename`, it is not a natural grouping column.  The corresponding `eid` would be better for several reasons.  That can be addressed by performing the aggregation via an (inline) view or common table expression:

```
SELECT employees.ename
FROM
  employees
  JOIN (
    SELECT certified.eid AS eid
    FROM
      certified
      JOIN aircraft ON aircraft.aid = certified.aid
    GROUP BY certified.eid
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 3
  ) AS mc
  ON employees.eid = mc.eid
```

That first joins `certified` to `aircraft`, aggregates the results by `eid`, and keeps only those groups meeting your criterion (`HAVING COUNT(*) > 3`), then joins the result to the `employees` table to get the `ename` for each `eid`.

An alternative implementation of essentially the same approach would be

```
SELECT ename
FROM employees
WHERE eid IN (
  SELECT certified.eid
  FROM
    certified
    JOIN aircraft ON aircraft.aid = certified.aid
  GROUP BY certified.eid
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 3
)
```

Depending on your data and DBMS, you may find that one of those runs faster than the other, but it is impossible to predict in general which one that would be.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is `HAVING` clause.  You want the count of the grouping (in this case e.ename) so you can't use `WHERE`.

```
SELECT e.ename
FROM employees e
JOIN certified c ON c.eid = e.eid
JOIN aircraft a ON a.aid = c.aid
GROUP BY e.ename
HAVING COUNT(e.ename) > 3
```

Comment: This, of course will merge the result into one if there are more than one employees with the exact same name (`e.ename`).  To prevent this problem, you can get the `e.eid` instead, then wrap it with outer query to grab the `e.ename`.